# How to set an onClickListener on an included layout?

Tags: android, onclicklistener

I have a layout with an ImageButton that I included in several other layouts.

**ImageButton Layout:**

**call_cancelled.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/callEndLayout"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:height="70dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/phoneEnd"
        android:layout_width="63dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:paddingBottom="7dp"
        android:background="@drawable/phone_cancelled"  />

</LinearLayout>
```

**My include:**

```
  <include
   android:id="@+id/includeCallEnd0"
   android:layout_width="70dp"
   android:layout_height="70dp"
   android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/include"
   android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   layout="@layout/call_cancelled" />
```

For this includes I need a onClickListener when it's pressed.
**I tried this:**

```
View endcall0 = (View) findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0);

 endcall0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL_BUTTON);
            startActivity(callIntent);

            int id = viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild();

            if (id == 0) {
                hideSoftKeyboard();
            }
        }
     });
```

But it doesn't work.
Does anybody know the solution?

Comment: `It doesn't work` means that code is not compiling or app is crashing at runtime?

Comment: Replace `findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0)` with `findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0).findViewById(R.id.phoneEnd)` and it should work

Comment: What type of widget is include?  Which class does it extend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0)` with `findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0).findViewById(R.id.phoneEnd)` and it should work

because you want to set the click listener on the ImageButton and not the whole layout

---

Use the following function to set the OnClickListener once:

```
private static void applyListener(View child, OnClickListener listener) {
    if (child == null)
        return;

    if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
        applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
    }
    else if (child != null) {
        if(child.getId() == R.id.phoneEnd) {
            child.setOnClickListener(listener);
        }
    }
}

private static void applyListener(ViewGroup parent, OnClickListener listener) {
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
            applyListener((ViewGroup) child, listener);
        } else {
            applyListener(child, listener);
        }
    }
}
```

Use `applyListener(rootView, yourOnClickListener);`

Comment: It works. thanks. Now I have to write an onClickListener for every single include. Is there a way to reach all includes with 1 onclickListener?

Comment: Sorry have a another question. whats the rootView?

Comment: rootView in this case is any parent any parent view that contains all your ImageButtons in the view hierarchy. In general, it is the first view in your xml, usually a LinearLayout or RelativeLayout or FrameLayout that contains everything else inside.

Comment: This answer is pure genius! Thank you so much Sherif.

Comment: What if I do want to put the listener on the whole layout?

Comment: @Hiro in that case add listener to top layout (LinearLayout in this case)

Answer (score 4):

You could have done

```
LinearLayout endcall0 = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.includeCallEnd0);
```

and then simply

```
ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) endcall0.findViewById(R.id. phoneEnd); 
imgBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Comment: Only this solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Try to set your clickListener on callEndLayout (LinearLayaout)

Answer (score 0):

very easy with Kotlin::

{appBar} is include view

{btnOrders} is button view inside appBar layout

```
binding.appBar.btnOrders.setOnClickListener {
   startActivity(Intent(this, OrdersActivity::class.java))
}
```