# onClickListener doesn't trigger when using <include layout

Tags: android, kotlin, onclicklistener

My clicklistener is not working anymore when adding it to it's own layout file.

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView<ActivityMainBinding>(
        this, R.layout.activity_main
    ).apply {
        lifecycleOwner = this@MainActivity
    }
    binding.progressIndicatorLayout.progressIndicator.setOnClickListener {
        Log.d("","Hello")
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progress_indicator_layout"
            layout="@layout/progress_indicator_layout" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**progress_indicator_layout:**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226259/how-to-set-an-onclicklistener-on-an-included-layout) and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43166731/android-data-binding-include-layout-onclick-listener-doesnt-work) but they are outdated / don't work.

Comment: add these to the progressIndicator, android:clickable="true"  android:focusable="true"

Answer (score 1):

I tried to copy your code and it works completely fine. I think you just need to clean the project and Invalidate Caches / Restart.

If still not working try to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32947440/android-data-binding-using-include-tag).